# Find missing among 1000 numbered files

Tags: linux

I have folder that should contain 1000 files, named `out_x.dat`, where `x` is a number from 1 to 1000. When I do `ls out_* | wc -l`, I see that there are 996 files. I would like to know which four are missing. How can I achieve this? I can list the existing files with this:

```
ls out* | awk -F '_' '{ print $2}'
```

Is there something that'll allow me to list the ones that don't exist within the 1000 files?

Comment: You can use a simple script to check the existence of each of the files in turn, eg `for (( i=1; i<=1000; ++i )); do [ -e out_$i.dat ] || echo out_$i.dat missing; done`.

Comment: If the number is formatted, say to 4 digits, the command line can be elaborated to `for (( i=1; i<=1000; ++i )); do printf -v n out_%04d.dat $i; [ -e $n ] || echo $n missing; done`.

Comment: @AFH or in bash/ksh/zsh more simply for fixedwidth `for i in {0001..1000}; do [ -e out_$i.dat ] ...; done` Another option is something like `diff <(ls out_* | sort -t_ -nk2) <(printf '%s\n' out_{1..1000}) # or 0001..1000`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Thanks, I'd forgotten about that construct. In fact, on Ubuntu `bash` I found that `{01..1000}` gives the same result, padding to the number of digits needed for the last number in the sequence; in contrast `{1..1000}` gives no leading digits.

Comment: I have submitted it as answer, so others can see it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple script to check the existence of each of the files in turn, eg:

```
for (( i=1; i<=1000; ++i )); do [ -e out_$i.dat ] || echo out_$i.dat missing; done
```

If the number is formatted, say to 4 digits, the command line can be elaborated to:

```
for (( i=1; i<=1000; ++i )); do printf -v n out_%04d.dat $i; [ -e $n ] || echo $n missing; done
```

Alternatively (thanks to @dave_thompson_085's comment):

```
for i in {0001..1000}; do [ -e out_$i.dat ]  || echo out_$i.dat missing; done
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify this to have a double loop that will loop over `out_$i_$j.dat`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate - Yes, of course: `for` statements can be nested: `for i ...; do for j ...; do ...; done; done`. Note that you will need to refer to `${i}_$j`, as `_` is a valid character in a variable name.